# WebRequest Connection Error Only When Server Executing Backend Work

Tags: vb.net

I've got a VB.NET app executing a simple WebRequest that is to interact with a web API. Through testing, I can successfully have the WebRequest executed and get a server response when I'm calling any static page on the server.

But when I execute a request of the API (which is interacting with a MySQL DB) the VB.NET app always throws this error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.

I do not get that error when I execute the same URL in a browser from the same PC. The API returns JSON encoded text with a text/plain content header.

Here is the VB.NET application code:

```
strURL = "https://soc-server.com/wireless/soc_wapi.php?&function=add_kb_event&logtype=33&datetime=2013-12-16%2013:50:50&kid=4&pid=1&peid=5&cid=97"

Dim ReturnValue As String = String.Empty
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(New Uri(strURL)), HttpWebRequest)



Try
                Dim ResponseText As String = String.Empty
                Using Response As HttpWebResponse = CType(Request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
                    Using ReceiveStream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream
                        Using ReadStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ReceiveStream)
                            ReturnValue = ReadStream.ReadToEnd
                            processLog(ReturnValue)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                processError(ex, "Error sending data")
            End Try
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing `Request.Timeout` or `Request.ReadWriteTimeout` ?

Comment: I've set Request.Timeout as high as 180000 (ms) but to no effect.

Comment: When executing in a browser, the same URL executes typically in < 1000 ms.

Comment: Just tried increasing ReadWriteTimeout as well to no avail.

Comment: If you're reading entire string value at once can you try just webclient approach? `Dim WC As WebClient = New WebClient()` `Dim ReturnValue As String = WC.DownloadString(strURL)` ?

Comment: Just issued that, same results ("works" on static pages, timeout error when issuing API page request).  Interestingly, even on a static page, it was 67 seconds between DownloadString beginning execution and when the app said it received the response and wrote it to log.

Comment: Are u going to that site thru any kind of proxy? E.g. anything in proxy settings of your browser? Is it internal site or accessible via Internet? Because URL as is doesn't work in browser for me (I guess it's not supposed to)

Comment: Yes, I'm at work and we use a proxy. I had set it earlier on WebRequest <code>Dim proxyObject As WebProxy = New WebProxy("http://ourproxyserver:3128/ Request.Proxy = proxyObject", but presently have it commented out as I wasn't seeing any differing results. But if it could be settings on the proxy itself, I should have a look?

Comment: I have a feeling proxy is involved. Maybe it requires authentication, maybe it cuts off certain connections. But you definitely should use it if it requires for connection.

Comment: I'm setting the proxy for the app again, and get much faster responses now. Unfortunately that hasn't resulted in my API request being successful. With webclient getting "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" again, going to try in a couple of hours from home.